# "Post Brine" for Lacto-Fermented Cucumbers (Dill Pickles)

Tags: fermentation

Once I have "pickles" pickled (pun intended)... how do I store them? Typically I make a very large batch and would like to transfer them to smaller vessels for friends/family... do I just pour in the brine I used to ferment them?

Comment: That really depends on how long you want them to be stored. If they aren't processed, i.e. canned then they will only last a short time in the refrigerator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the brine you pickled them in. Covered plastic leftover containers are actually very good for storing pickles - you don't have to struggle to stuff them in jars. You can throw away the dill weed and garlic and other flavorings, just keep the pickles and enough strained brine to keep them submerged.

Keep in mind, of course, that such pickles are not preserved, so they must be stored in the fridge, and should be eaten within a short amount of time - one or two weeks at most.

Comment: Thanks! Pickles don't last very long in my presence... so, I don't think that'll be a problem :)

Comment: Pickles don't survive long if my brother-in-law is in the vicinity, either, so I'm actually totally unsure what the maximum storage time is - a couple of weeks is my best guess, but I don't think we've ever had pickles around for longer than a week, and that's if they're well-hidden in the bottom of a cooler at a two-week camping event. :)